# setRequestHeader Scopes href from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a link on the website. After clicking the link, it takes me to another page, but in the browser bar it is a different link than the one I clicked on.

There must be some redirection on the server.

For example

`<a href="brand=alaxo/products,2"></a>` redirect me to "/products/chosen-products/alaxo,2,5138"

I would like to retrieve the website address after redirect.

I've run jQuery .get() function on link "brand=alaxo/products,2" to find this information.

It seems to be on setRequestHeader section like below.

[image]

How can I get this value and change link in  tag.

Thank you for any help.

Best regards

Maciej

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using fetch() instead of get()

Maciej